# Cocoa NSTextField text get cut off in view after changed to monospaced digital font

Tags: swift, cocoa

The text inside `NSTextField` gets cut off when I have the font changed to `monospacedDigitSystemFont`.

I have the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method. I do not understand why it has been cut off since `sizeToFit` has been called and the intrinsic size should be used.

The label at the bottom looks fine and it is using the default system font.

```
    labelTimeNow.sizeToFit()
    labelTimeNow.font = NSFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(
        ofSize: labelTimeNow.font!.pointSize,
        weight: .medium
    )
    labelTimeNow.stringValue = DCClock.getCurrentTimeInFormat("HH:mm")
```

[image]

**Reference**

- [How can I set NSTableView column to use monospaced numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954528/how-can-i-set-nstableview-column-to-use-monospaced-numbers/33975940#33975940)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me, I should call `sizeToFit` after changing the font spacing.

```
    labelTimeNow.font = NSFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(
        ofSize: labelTimeNow.font!.pointSize,
        weight: .medium
    )
    labelTimeNow.stringValue = DCClock.getCurrentTimeInFormat("HH:mm")
    labelTimeNow.sizeToFit()
```